External keyboard cannot connect
I have trouble connecting my new keyboard, Logitec Ergo K860, via bluetooth.
When I do the pairing, an infobox emerges on my laptop, where I am asked to type a 6-digit-pin on the keyboard and press enter in order to confirm the pairing. I do so, and it works. In other words, data is indeed transferred from the keyboard to the laptop in this case. But afterwards, the laptop takes no input from the keyboard.
Here are some clues:
Laptop: Lenovo ThinkPad W550s.
OS: Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS (Gnome 3).
My laptop has no trouble connecting other bluetooth devices.
The keyboard can connect to other laptops (which also runs ubuntu)
Under settings -> Bluetooth, the keyboard apperars to be paired and connected.
But when I write "xinput list" in terminal, only the laptop's own keyboard appears.
Here is the output of writing "xinput list" in terminal:
"
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint                     id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Synaptics TM3053-003                      id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ ThinkPad Extra Buttons                    id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ Sleep Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ Video Bus                                 id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ UE MEGABOOM (AVRCP)                       id=15   [slave  keyboard (3)]
∼ ELAN Touchscreen                          id=10   [floating slave]
"
The output of writing "xinput list" in terminal does not change, regardless of whether the external keyboard is turned on and lists as connected in bluetooth settings, or not.
The batteries are fully charged.
I have restarted the keyboard, the laptop and the bluetooth connection several times.
I have updated with sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade.
I have asked ChatGPT.
I have downloaded Solaar, but Solaar only shows a blank list, with no connected devices.
Feel free to ask any questions you need to help me troubleshoot.
I kindly ask for clear explanations, as I am absolutely no computer expert.
Thanks in advance!

Please clarify this statement from your question. write "xinput list" in terminal, only the laptop's own keyboard appears. Does this mean you have tried it with each keyboard? Please update the question with edit and add this info.

Thanks, @David. I have updated my question with the output of writing xinput list in terminal. I have tried writing "xinput list" both with and without the external keyboard. The output of writing "xinput list" in terminal does not change, regardless of whether the external keyboard is turned on and lists as connected in bluetooth settings, or not. Please tell me if you need any other information.
